# Will registering an observer multiple times have any effects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotifications

If I register for the same event multiple times, will it do anything? Or will I need to unregister that many times? If the latter, how can I check to see if I'm already registered to receive a particular event?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will receive notifications multiple times. The docs claim there are some situations where you would want this, though I can't think of any.

You can use `removeObserver:` or `removeObserver:name:object:` immediately before adding the observer, to ensure it isn't added multiple times. There is nothing wrong with calling `removeObserver:` with an object that isn't actually observing a notification.

Alternatively (and this is probably the highest performance and most reliable option) you could create your own `NSSet` object to store exactly what objects you've added to that specific notification, and check if the one you're about to add a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> There is nothing wrong with calling `removeObserver:` with an object that isn't actually observing a notification.

I tried to do that, because I thought if it was implemented well, it wouldn't complain about removing an object without the object being registered as an observer. But I got an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "aKeyPath" from  because it is not registered as an observer.'

So, actually, you have to manage yourself, if you are observer or not. That is quite ridiculous in comparison to the luxury of iOS-development.

Comment: The accepted answer is about observers for notifications via the NSNotificationCenter, not for KVO (Key Value Observers) which indeed throw an exception for removing. Sometimes you'll have to just catch this exception and move on.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *obString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", session.observationInfo];
NSRange rangeOfKey = [obString rangeOfString:observedKey];

if (rangeOfKey.location != NSNotFound) {
    //
    NSLog(@"observing");
    [session removeObserver:self forKeyPath:observedKey];
}
else {
    //
    NSLog(@"not observing");
}
```